# Get parents directories of a file, up to a point

Tags: python

If I have a path for a given file, say `'C:\Folder\OtherFolder\AnotherFolder\file.txt'`, is there a way in python I can get all the parent directories for file.txt up to `'OtherFolder'`? The depth of the path is not constant, so I can't just iterate back a certain number of times, but I always need to get up to `'OtherFolder'` regardless of depth. I feel like this should be easier than I'm making it, but they say Thursday is the new Monday. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Windows, try this:

```
import os
os.path.relpath('C:\Folder\OtherFolder\AnotherFolder\file.txt', 'C:\Folder\OtherFolder')
```

You can then split it using `os.path.sep` (in your case `\`):

```
rel_path.split(os.path.sep)
```

to get the individual directories.

On a Linux machine a similar call returns what you mean:

```
os.path.relpath('/Folder/OtherFolder/AnotherFolder/file.txt', '/Folder/OtherFolder')
# returns 'AnotherFolder/file.txt'

rel_path.split(os.path.sep)
# returns ['AnotherFolder', 'file.txt']
```